# How to enable/activate openchrome driver?

Tags: 10.10, drivers, vga, via, openchrome

I have installed Ubuntu 10.10 on a PC at my work, but my graphics don't work. Some examples: my mouse is a block with some pixels, my taskbars are completely white and I see no text and no pictures. Even when I open the terminal by using the short cut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> I see a with window. I have installed the Openchrome Drivers but I don't know how to enable/activate them. Or is there an other solution. I use the standard ubuntu shell.

The specs of the computer are:

- Motherboard: Asus M2V-MX(chipset: VIA K8M890 + 8237A)
- CPU: AMD Sempron 3400+
- Ram: Kingston 512MB DDR2
- HDD: Hitachi 80GB Sata Drive

I hope that someone can help my.

Yours sincerely,

Youri de Groot

Answer (score 2):

1. Download and install the [OpenChrome deb file](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/xserver-xorg-video-openchrome_0.2.904+svn920-1build2_i386.deb).
2. Open the file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` in an editor.
3. Look for the section `Device`
4. Add the line `driver "openchrome"`. Save and Exit.
5. Restart the machine. That's it